# Normalization when min(x)=0

Tags: terminology

I wish to know if there is a special name for normalization when $\min(x)=0$; so that the recipe

$z_i= [x_i−\min(x)]\ /\ [\max(x)−\min(x)]$

becomes

$z_i=x_i/\max(x)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Division or scaling by the maximum** would work fine for me. There doesn't have to be a single word for every slightly different procedure. In fact that would be a nightmare to learn and to teach.

What you could easily do is add a sentence of explanation:

> As minimum values are 0, scaling using the observed range to [0, 1]
>   reduces to dividing by the maximum.

I'd add a standard warning: using *normalization* as a term in this way seems more common in machine learning  (ML) than in statistics mainstream. If you are working in ML, then that likely wouldn't bite.

In statistics there might be a sense that the word *normalization* meant transforming to be closer to a normal distribution (e.g. by taking logarithms of a right skewed positive variable). That is another reason why words can be treacherous. Showing people the simple algebra cuts through any ambiguity.